# Why am I getting an invalid JSON after serialization using EF?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following two models, `PatientRegistry` and `PartnerRegistry`. The relationship between those models is one to many.

I am trying to read the record and its related one but I am getting a broken JSON at `PartnerRegistry`. The only way I got it to work is by using Automapper, but why is this happening? Do I need to call the context for the second model? My understanding is that EF will automatically do that once a relationship is established.

**EDIT**

I removed some prop just to shorten the list

```
[Table("PatientsRegistry")]
    public class PatientRegistry
    {   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Record Id")]
        public long RecordId { get; set; }
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Patient File Number")]
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(50)]        
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PartnerRegistry> Partners { get; set; }
        public PatientRegistry()
        {
            Partners = new Collection<PartnerRegistry>();
        }

    }
public class PartnerRegistry
    {   
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long RecordId { get; set; }
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
        public long PartnerFileId { get; set; }
        public PatientRegistry PatientsRegistry { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    }
```

and my controller is

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getAll(long Ids)
    {
          var patient = await context.PatientsRegistry
        .Include(pt => pt.Gender)
        .Include(pt => pt.Partners)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(pt => pt.PatientFileId == Ids);

        return Ok(patient);
    }
```

The output is

```
{
    "recordId": 1,
    "patientFileId": 1111,
    "firstName": "John",
    "secondName": "M",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "genderId": 1,
    "gender": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Male"
    },
    "dateCreated": "2017-11-25T08:40:07.75444",
    "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAAB9E=",
    "partners": [{
                "recordId": 1,
                "patientFileId": 1111,
                "partnerFileId": 2222
```

You can notice that there are missing properties that were not mapped by ef! 
The properties that were not populated are, `StartDate` and `EndDate`

Comment: could you describe which properties that are? the list is quite long!

Comment: I apologize for the long list, related model has the following,`public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }` and `public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }`

Comment: I shorten the list

Comment: could the serializer skip the null properties? what if you try to add the `= DateTime.UtcNow;` for those 2, just to check that the dates are filled?

Comment: The fields are not `null`, one of them `StartDate` is required

Comment: your json is not correct yet, that just a CTRL+V parsing error?

Comment: yes agreed, I have no idea why its being parsed in this way, even if the one of the prop is `null` I should be getting a correctly parsed JSON regardless

Comment: The output JSon is still invalid (truncated), is that really what comes out? Otherwise, correct this. And/or tell us how you captured the results.

Comment: I know that my JSON is invalid, I will add the missing properties to the question

Comment: I think this will turn into a question about how you call this service. Elaborate about the client, tell us you used a browser, and which ones.

Comment: We are not just missing some propertiers, the lack of `}]}` is much more critical.

Comment: So I am used the following, safari browser, chrome browser, Postman and swagger. the latter one just does not produce any response, the rest give me the above truncated `JSON`

Comment: yes this is why I called it broken or what you called invalid, your description is better than mine

Comment: Look in your service logs, I suspect it goes into a circle on PartnerRegistry.PatientsRegistry , breaking the stack. Some JSon attribute may be required.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on how to find these logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix:

```
public class PartnerRegistry
{   
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RecordId { get; set; }
    public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
    public long PartnerFileId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]  // add this
    public PatientRegistry PatientsRegistry { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Edit, a small mcve:

```
class Patient
{
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Partner> Partners { get; set; }
}

class Partner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //[JsonIgnore]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

with thes classes and Partners filled,

```
string text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patient1);
```

will throw

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Patient' with type 'App1.Patient'. Path 'Partners[0]'.'

Comment: is this normal to happen in ef? or is there something wrong with my model design?

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with EF.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, what is it then

Comment: This is all about JSon. With your chosen username, you should be answering questions like this, not asking them (-;

Comment: I am changing my username immediately, I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Now I get it, as I mentioned above, I solved it by automapper using DTOs that stem from these models. I just wanted to understand why is this happening and how to go around it in case I dont want to use automapper. Thanks for the elaborative response

Answer (score 1):

Put `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on the `PatientRegistry` Property of the `PartnerRegistry` class. This attribute is available from `System.Web.Script.Serialization`. There could be a circular references halting the serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update:

also I found that this problem can be resolved globally via this configuration,

```
    services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => 
     options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
     Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)